# My macro is not assignable

Tags: objective-c, macros

I'm trying to define a macro that returns an absolute value of numbers. Here how it looks like:

```
#define ABSOLUTE_VALUE(v) ( (v) < 0 ? (v) *= -1 : (v))
```

It works fine when I insert just a single number. The problem is, when I try to insert an expression (`number + anotherNumber`, for example), the compiler throws an error, saying that the expression is not assignable. I can't figure out why it does that. If you know the reason of the error, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: How should `(number + anotherNumber) *= -1` behave?

Comment: Why do you write another macro for getting the absolute value of a number? There is already an `ABS` macro for that. Just use it.

Comment: @hop, I believe, the operation `number + anotherNumber` should return yet another number, which will be multiplied by -1

Comment: @ozgur, this is an assignment. I know that there already exists a macro for that purpose :)

Comment: `*=` is not  multiplication, `*` is. `*=` is an assignment.

Comment: @hop, well I assign `v * (-1)` to `v`

Comment: just think about the answer below until you understand it.

Comment: @hop, I got it. The problem is that I'm trying to assign the result of `(number + anotherNumber) * (-1)` to an expression, which is `number + anotherNumber`. But shouldn't the `+` fire first, before the `*=` operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's going on here is that the entire expression `number + anotherNumber` is getting passed to your macro, so anywhere there is `v`, it's not the result `v = number + anotherNumber`, rather, `v` is replaced by `number + anotherNumber` before evaluation. So:

```
 (v) *= -1
```

Becomes

```
(number + anotherNumber) *= -1
```

Since `number + anotherNumber` is yet another number, that part of the code is trying to assign the value of `-1 * (number + anotherNumber)` to `number + anotherNumber` , which results in the error you are seeing, because you can't assign something to an expression.

Comment: So, you are saying that the operation `number + anotherNumber` doesn't occur, and instead, `v` is replaced by that expression, right? But shouldn't the parenthesis around `v` make the `+` operation occur first (which will result to another number)?

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan Yes, but what happens if you do `5 *= -1` for example? It tries to store the value `-5` into `5`, but `5` is an expression, not a variable. It does work with just one variable because if it does `(number) *= -1`, then it stores `-1*number` into the variable `number`, but in the case of the result of `number + anotherNumber`, that's an expression, not a variable, after it's reduced.

Comment: So, in your comment above, 5 is a result of a `number + anotherNumber`, right?

Comment: Yes, 5 was just an example of what that sum could be. Though I guess a negative number would have been a better example because that part of the code is only run when `v` is negative, but it's still the same issue.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you for your explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

From one of your comments:

> The problem is that I'm trying to assign the result of (number + anotherNumber) * (-1) to an expression, which is number + anotherNumber. But shouldn't the + fire first, before the *= operator?

You are misunderstanding *assignment*. The left hand side (LHS) of an assignment must be an *lvalue*, which means something like a *variable*, which references a storage location into which values can be stored.

A *value* is just that, it is not associated with any storage location, you cannot assign to it. The result of your expression `number + anotherNumber` is a number, it cannot go on the LHS of an assignment.

Your macro would work if you simply replace `=*` with `*`.

HTH

Comment: So the result of the expression `number  + anotherNumber` can't be on the LHS of an assignment because it is not a variable, but just a number, so it doesn't have a storage location, right?

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan - Exactly